# Resetting app after turning it down by the Multitable bar

Tags: iphone, ios, multitasking

I have a problem with my app.
I would like to 'reset' my app each time when I turn it down by the multitasking bar.
I found UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend (or as in the newest Xcode: 
'Application does not run in background') which has to be added to the info.plist.
But this method resets my app each time when I go to the background mode.
Is there any method (as the ones above) which makes the app reset but only if I 'kill' it by the multitasking bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I misunderstand you, but if you kill an app by closing it in the multitasking bar, it's killed, done, gone. So if you start it again afterwards it should be reset.

Comment: I want to get the same result as by UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend. This makes that the app is starting all over again (without setting etc) as a new one. But this function is by clicking the home button. And I would like to get it by removing the app from the Multitask bar.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say. In my experience if you remove the app from the multitasking bar, it **does** start all over again the time you start it.

Comment: Well, may I didn't express good. Of course, the app will start again, but it will have set everything as before shutting down the app.
With UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend, I got the app as a new one (without nothing).